# Phonegap + ReactJS White Screen

Tags: reactjs, cordova, phonegap

**TL;DR:** A fresh app built with `create-react-app` and `yarn build`, then copied into a new Phonegap project's /www directory results in a white screen when loading the app in the Phonegap Developer app via `phonegap serve`.

---

I've been working on a ReactJS app for some time now and am currently in the process of porting it to Phonegap to create hybrid mobile apps for Android & iOS.

I have gone through the Phonegap setup, and successfully got their demo project (that is generated by running `phonegap create`) running in the Phonegap Developer app.

However, when I create a new react app via `create-react-app` (or use my existing app), run `yarn build` to create a production build, then copy the contents of /build into /www for Phonegap, running the app in the Phonegap Developer app results in a white screen.

The output of `phonegap serve` when I open the app in the Phonegap Developer app is as follows:

```
[phonegap] [console.warn] Content Security Policy has been added: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;img-src * 'self' data: content:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
[phonegap] 200 /__api__/appzip
```

With the server running I can successfully access the app by navigating to it's IP directly in Chrome for Android, but trying to load it in the Phonegap Developer app still leads to a white screen.

The output from `phonegap serve` when loading the app in a browser is as follows:

```
[phonegap] 200 /
[phonegap] 200 /static/css/main.7b1984ad.css
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/socket.io.js
[phonegap] 200 /static/js/main.48127ccb.js
[phonegap] 200 /static/css/main.7b1984ad.css.map
[phonegap] 200 /img/nav-logo.png
[phonegap] 200 /img/welcome-logo.png
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MLheCGT
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MLheCOR&sid=Q1drCs6tvCUbSX_FAAAA
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MLheCSj&sid=Q1drCs6tvCUbSX_FAAAA
[phonegap] 200 /static/js/main.48127ccb.js.map
```

I've also confirmed that no JS errors are being thrown when the app loads.

If anyone has a solution or any ideas at all it would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create-react-app is set to fetch the resources from the root folder which will be the root of the phone's file system. I fixed the problem by adding 
`"homepage": "./"` key value pair in package.json of the create-react-app app